# Updating Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, backgroundworker

I'm writing a program to help with a game. I need it to update the text box that shows the current exp value, on the forum load it does show the exp, I need it to update the `exp` like every *`3 seconds`*.

How would I go about doing that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
        Client C = Client.GetClients()[0];
        Player P;
        P = C.GetPlayer();
        expTextBox.Text = ("Experience: " + P.Experience.ToString());
```

I am not sure if I need a `timer` (which i have tried and I am very bad at making) or if a `backGroundWorker` would be best.

Comment: Why do you need to update experience every 3 seconds, are they constantly gaining exp? If not, seems like a waste to update something until it actually changes?

Comment: Well not necissarily 3 seconds, but a constant value. I think 10 would be good. But yes they would be getting exp pretty constant.

Comment: The best method depends on the UI platform you're using.  What is it?  asp.net, winforms, etc..

Comment: Yes but do they gain exp based on some event, or is it something that automatically occurs? If it is based on pre-existing events, you use those, not a timer. It really depends on HOW they gain exp that you should update the UI.

Comment: Well the plan is to have them gain exp on attacking.  Im using Windows Forms Application. RIght now the event is nothing, it is them attacking in the game client

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I would recommend that you update your UI when your player/s are attacking, and not use a timer. This will keep your UI the most up-to-date and will probably serve you better than a 3 or 10 second timer. You will have a method like this:

```
public void Attack(Enemy e)
{
  //do your attack code

  //did the enemy die?
  KillEnemy();

  //add exp just for landing a successful attack
  AddExp(e);
}

public void AddExp(Enemy e)
{
  CurrentPlayer.Exp += e.ExperienceGain;

  //update the UI with the new exp
  GameWindow.ExperienceBox.Text = CurrentPlayer.Exp;
}
```

This is of course more pseudocode, because I have no idea what your design looks like, but I've made quite a few games, and this is how I always do it.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use Timer if you go to the background worker with infinite loop that is okay but you need to take care of two things when you use background workers:

1. Updating textbox or any other UI won't work as it needs to be done from the main thread. so you need to check myTextbox.requireInvoke() function before.
2. Check if the background worker got a cancel signal to exist the infinite loop.

on the other side. you will consume some time  when you use timers to update the text box. as the timer would go to the event processing cycle in the windows then fire the event and finally you will write the code in the timer event.